# Horizontal product reorder in Google Optimize

Tags: google-optimize

I have listed the 7 products horizontally. I want to reorder them through Google optimize. I did through drag & drop method in google optimize but when is preview it then it shows the original listing.
What should i do to reordering the products?
Thanks

i used drag & dop options bit not working

Answer (score 0):

It's possible javascript is overriding your reorder, you may need to create a second list of products on the site with the order you want to test and then hide it with CSS. Then for the experiment, hide the original and show the variant with CSS again.